# Array of structs with new[] doesn't seem to work if said struct have constructor

Tags: c++, struct, new-operator

For an assignment I have a struct with constructor defined and wish to create array of these using new[] operator. I can't understand why this doesn't work. The code is like so (pseudo code):

```
struct Structname 
{
int x;
int y;
Structname(int a,int b)
{
x=a;
y=b;
}
}
```

Now trying to do:

```
Structname *Array = new Structname[size]
```

Results in error "No function matching call Structname::Structname() on Structname[size]" (not exact citation). The error doesn't occur when there is no constructor in my struct just as if the compiler expects me to use the constructor in Structname* Array = new Structname[size]. I cannot delete the constructor because I need it in other parts of the code. Also I cannot use std::vector due to assignment rules.

Comment: Once you have defined a constructor, the default constructor is not created automatically. You need to define one

Comment: What value of `x` and `y` should each element of `Array` hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define parameterised constructor, the compiler doesn't inject the default constructor i.e. `Structname::Structname()`. That's why you are getting error.

You may get past it in two ways:

1) Define your own default constructor:

```
struct Structname {
    int x;
    int y;
    Structname(int a,int b) {
        x=a;
        y=b;
    }
    Structname(): Structname(0, 0) { }
}
```

2) Use `default` keyword to get constructor which was supposed to be injected by compiler.

```
struct Structname {
    int x;
    int y;
    Structname(int a,int b) {
        x=a;
        y=b;
    }
    Structname() = default;
}
```

Please note that in option 1, the data members are initialized with proper values. In option 2, data members won't be initialized to proper values.

So, make your choice based on the requirement.

**Suggestion:**

Though pretty unrelated to the problem, it is considered a good practice. Never use *naked* new. Look for other options instead. See `std::vector`.

Comment: Thank you, this explains all.